# Is $f(x)=1-e^{-x}, \;0 \leq x \leq 1, \;\; f(x)=(e-1)e^{-x}, \; x>1 $ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Is the following function,

\begin{align}f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1-e^{-x}, & \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
    (e-1)e^{-x}, & \text{for } x>1 
  \end{cases}\end{align}
differentiable?

**My Trial**

Let $f_1(x)=1-e^{-x},\;\;0\leq x\leq 1,$ and $f_2(x)=(e-1)e^{-x},\;\;x>1.$ Then,
\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\dfrac{f_1(x)-f_1(1)}{x-1}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\dfrac{(1-e^{-x})-(1-e^{-1})}{x-1}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1}\;\;\text{(L'Hopital's rule)}\\&=e^{-1}\end{align}

\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}}\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}}\dfrac{f_2(x)-f_2(1)}{x-1}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}}\dfrac{(e-1)e^{-x}-(e-1)e^{-1}}{x-1}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}}\dfrac{(e-1)(e^{-x}-e^{-1})}{x-1}\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}}\dfrac{(1-e)e^{-x}}{1}\;\;\text{(L'Hopital's rule)}\\&=e^{-1}-1\end{align}

As it stands, they are not equal. So, it's not differentiable. I'm I right or missing something?

Comment: You are right. The right-derivative is not equal to the left-derivative at the point $x=1$, hence the function is not differentiable, because a derivative cannot have jump discontinuities. There is a minor typo: in the first line of the right-limit, it should be $f_2$, not $f_1$.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Thanks a lot for the comments. I've edited it.

Comment: By the way, a quicker way is to simply compute the right and left derivatives without calculating limits - by direct differentiation, and to compare the results. If they are not equal, the function is not differentiable at that point.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Oh, thanks for that! I'm grateful!